# What happens to articles when dealing with abbrevations?

Tags: article, abbreviation

What is the rule about articles when it comes to abbreviations? Let’s say I have a noun *der Professor* (for a female it would be *die Professorin*, but that is irrelevant here). I would like to use abbreviated form — would I get *der Prof.* or just *Prof.*?

Comment: Depends on the context. Can you give an example?

Comment: @Robert, I answer with a question -- do you have an example of the sentence where you have "...... der Professor...." and after abbreviating it you get the same sentence reading " ...... Prof. .... " (i.e. without "der")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article is determined by the abbreviated word (*der* Prof.), or the main/last word in a compound (*die* NATO, *der* EuGH, etc.)

When the abbreviation becomes a word in its own right, so to speak, the article is often dropped (AIDS, not *das* AIDS).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the circumstances.

If you are addressing somebody, e.g. in a letter or an email, there is no article in the first place. It would be *Herr Professor Mayr* or *Hr. Prof. Mayr* — although the latter is typically not acceptable at all. (‘If you’re going to write it, have the decency to write out the title’ is the general rule.)

If you are writing in a text where an article is required, it will of course still be there and determined by the word in question.

> Der Prof. besucht die Einrichtung.
>
> Die Prof./Prof.in besucht die Einrichtung.

However, I would still argue that that is an unlikely case. If you have the need to abbreviate, you may just want to go all the way:

> D. Prof. bes. d. Einricht.

Comment: Thank you but you added too much story to my question. Say I have a sentence or whatever and the text is "....... der Professor.......". When I use abbreviation instead of entire noun, do I drop gender particle or not?

Comment: @greenoldman Is ‘Der Prof. besucht die Einrichtung’ not enough of an example? (Also, it is not a ‘gender particle’; please stop calling it that. It is a (definite) article.)

Comment: it is, that's why I upvoted your answer :-) I only pointed out that I have the text already with nouns (full) so there is no such case as "If you are addressing somebody...".

Comment: @greenoldman Ah! I wasn’t sure from your question what exactly you have :)